# Indexing multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, indexing

Imagine I have a table which has three simple columns; `PersonName`, `PersonLastName` and `Phone_Number`.

I have created and indexing such as

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON phonebook (PersonName,PersonLastName);
```

When I search for a name the performance will surely increase but what about if I search for the lastname ? Will this statement make two different indexing according to the `PersonName` and `PersonLastName` or a single indexing just for the `PersonName`?

Comment: MySQL has pretty good documentation on multi-column indexes (and the ideas apply to most databases):  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Index _usage_ highly depends on the DBMS and the query optimizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement only creates a single index, sorted by `PersonName` and then by `PersonLastName`. It won't be useful if your query searches only by `PersonLastName` and not by `PersonName`. You could, however, create an additional index in the opposite order:

```
CREATE INDEX another_index ON phonebook (PersonLastName, PersonName);
```

This isn't just possible - it is, in fact, a common practice.